# Whats the deal with Spatial Durbin Models and non-spattial interactions?

Tags: regression, econometrics, spatial, spatial-interaction-model

I have really been curious about this, but I have been searching around for studies which utilize Spatial Durbin models and I have yet to find any one model that has incorporated the use of interaction effects. For instance, imagine it a Durbin model was executed and you see results like this...

```
Coefficients:
                           Estimate  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)             -2.0324e-02  0.8452031
DummyX                   3.5832e-01  0.0290771
X1                       2.5424e-02  0.7522377
X1:DummyX               -4.3316e-01  0.0001841
LagDummyX                3.1791e-02  0.0567951
LagX1                    1.4026e-02  0.0015517
LagX1:DummyX            -9.6428e-03  0.3418146
```

I don't see any kinds of models like this. I have seen the use of both continuous and discrete variables but never a SDM utilizing an interaction between the two. Why is that the case? I think there may be difficulty with interpretation, granted, but these studies do not seem to even mention the disregard of using said interactions, which seem theoretically viable for me. I have run a few models that appear to have different I don't really get it. Anyone with spatial regression experience? Any help would be very appreciated.